# Nested div in ion-col, 100% height not work in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic2

I use ionic 2.

I have the follwing template:

**HTML**

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
     <ion-col width-20>
         <div>
             <img src="http://www.kacholy.com/new_site/pic/image_7276.jpg">
        </div>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="secondaryPic" width-20>
         <div class="placeHolder"></div>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="secondaryPic" width-20>
         <div class="placeHolder"></div>
     </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

**css:**

```
.placeHolder{
        width: 100%;
        height: 97%;
        border: 2px solid deeppink
    }
```

**Here is the result at chrome - work well**:

http://jmp.sh/spLNqZl

here is the result at safary, and this is the result on IOS device.
 - the problem is that **div not stretched to all of ion-col height**. In view-inspector I see that the ion-col get the height of the image near.

http://jmp.sh/aKQZuIV

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've added this to overcome this issue

```
ion-grid,
ion-row,
ion-col {
   height: 100%;
}
```